# Code to get s3 path of tables in Athena database

Tags: python, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-athena

Hi so there 1000 athena tables whoose s3 path has to be noted.Getting s3 location from ddl for individual tables is a monotonous job. So ,I was looking for a code to get s3 path of the athena table. The tables belong to a specific database in athena.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you want to get S3 location from the table DDL statement, or do you want to somehow get information from S3 about which prefixes are a source for an Athena table?

Comment: Hi so there 1000 athena tables whoose s3 path has to be noted.Getting s3 location from ddl for individual tables is a monotonous job. So ,I was looking for a code to get s3 path of the athena table. The tables belong to a specific database in athena.